# Differences between arm "versions?" (ARMv7 only)

Tags: linux, arm, cpu-architecture, abi

Basically I would like to know the difference between ARMv7l and ARMv7**h**l?

I got a arm processor with armv7l and there are a lot of rpm's for armv7**h**l.

I don't exactly know what I have to search for to get information about that.

What is this "suffix" called? Are there any other types? What are they doing differently?

Comment: @dwelch Maybe because you know what you have look for. I didn't find it. And I am not an google "softcore" user :P. So please, just show me your results.

Comment: google armv7l vs armv7hl which my browser filled in for me as soon as I soon as I typed the first l. then that lead to versions showing that the h means hardfp

Comment: as well as a list of other nomenclatures which is the second half of your question are there other types...

Comment: And now of course this question is the first search result for `armv7l vs armv7h`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would assume that it's indicating packages compiled for **l**ittle-endian and **h**ard-float ABI as appropriate - i.e. it's a software thing and only tangentially related to the hardware.

In other words, you don't actually have an "armv7l" processor - you have an ARMv7 processor which may well have a hardware FPU (and can run big-endian if you really wanted to), but you happen to be running a soft-float userspace that doesn't *rely* on one being present - just like running an i686 distribution doesn't imply you're *not* on an x86_64 machine. Different Linux distributions have different names for their various ports but some trivial poking around suggests this case might be openSUSE's convention.

Comment: I would be useful if answer provided a way to check whether you have hardware FPU.

Comment: Typically `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will return the features for your processor, and you are looking for "vfp" feature with possibly versions vfpv2 to vfpv5. "neon" is also floating point SIMD extensions for single precision useful for DSP math. You'll still need to ensure your OS and apps are compiled to use those instruction sets though.