# strptime() produces wrong result on armv7l environment

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t make_time(char *input, char *hs) {
    struct tm t;

    char d[17];
    strcpy(d, input);
    strcat(d, hs);
    d[16] = '\0';

    strptime(d, "%m%d%Y%H:%M:%S", &t);

    printf("data: %s", asctime(&t));

    return mktime(&t);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *s = argv[1];
    char *e = argv[2];

    time_t now = time(NULL);
    time_t start = make_time(s, "00:00:00");
    time_t end = make_time(e, "23:59:59");

    int s1 = difftime(now, start);
    int s2 = difftime(end, now);

    int ret = 0;
    if (s1 > 0 && s2 > 0) {
        ret = 1;
    }

    printf("Result:\nInput: %s %s\nDiff: start: %d; end: %d\nret: %d\n", s, e, s1, s2, ret);

    printf("\n");
}
```

2 versions were built. One is for use on debian linux & the other for an arm device.

On debian linux, the result looks right:

```
devbox@debian:~$ ./a.out 11182015 11302015
data: Wed Nov 18 00:00:00 2015
data: Mon Nov 30 23:59:59 2015
Result:
Input: 11182015 11302015
diff: start: 665291; end: 457908
ret: 1
```

But on armv7l env, `strptime()` produces wrong result:

```
# /tmp/a.out 11182015 11302015
data: ??? Jan  8 ??:??:?? 1900
data: ??? Jan  8 ??:??:?? 1900
Result:
Input: 11182015 11302015
diff: start: 1448437831; end: -1448437831
ret: 0
```

Is there something wrong with strptime on armv7l or is it not a standard GNU C method?

**UPDATE**

Here is the result of `uname` command:

```
# uname -a
Linux buildroot 3.1.0-xg3517-1.1 #1 Tue Mar 12 12:54:57 JST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Cortex A9 architecture, I guess.

Comment: @LPs: That would be ARMv7M/R/A. Still the OS is missing.

Comment: Looks like you pass invalid data.

Comment: @Olaf Could be compiled with little endian?

Comment: @Olaf Please look at my test results. You'll see that I passed the same data for both tests.

Comment: @LPs: Isn't that normal now for ARM, too?

Comment: @Olaf Yes, it is, AFAIK. I found [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166619/differences-between-arm-versions-armv7-only) post.

Comment: @LPs: Ok, now I got what you mean! Sorry, My CPU just runs at 1/10th clock today:-)

Comment: @RyanB: You did not show the values you pass to `strptime`.

Comment: @Olaf Please look into `make_time()` method.

Comment: 1) there are no _methods_ in C. 2) Sorry, I meant `asctime`, i.e. `t` and the value it generates.

Comment: I found [THIS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IZ85537) Try `strptime(d, "%m % d %Y %H:%M:%S", &t);`

Comment: @LPs I tried with `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"`. Still the same result.

Comment: I tried your code on my Cortex A9 embedded HW, and it works well. Could be something bugged on your libs or something not activated in your kernel?

Comment: Is `__USE_XOPEN` defined for your armv7 sdk?

Comment: @LPs __USE_XOPEN is already defined as 1.

Comment: @LP: One should not set `#define`s starting with `__` directly. Here in this case use `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE`.

Comment: Note: `time_t make_time(char *input, char *hs) { ...printf("Invalid parameter!\n");  return;` is a problem as _nothing_ is returned.  Suggest `return -1;`.

Comment: Minor: `char d[17]; strcpy(d, input); strcat(d, hs);` is a problem if `strlen(hs) > 8`.

Comment: @chux Thanks. 1) I'd edited the code to remove unnecessary part. 2) This is the test program because my main application doesn't work on armv7 device. Frankly, I just want to know why `strptime()` produces wrong result & I am barely pass any wrong data to the char d[17]. Hence, no need to check for the data size.

Comment: `d[16] = '\0';` is redundant. If you already overflowed the buffer it's too late. To avoid any chance of buffer overflows influencing this, use `snprintf(d, sizeof d, "%s%s", input, hs);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally know why & make it works. The problem is: `strptime()` seems to have no idea how to parse the following formats:

```
"%m%d%Y%H:%M:%S"
// or
"%m%d%Y %H:%M:%S"
// or
"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

But, if I use this: `"%m-%d-%Y %T"`

```
strptime(d, "%m-%d-%Y %T", &t);
```

Then it works, what a shame !

I don't know why those formats are not accepted, since doc didn't say anything about those which are not being fully implemented. Anyway, if anyone knows why, please shed me some light.

Comment: It's probably consuming too many digits for each field descriptor.